# Can you cancel a close vote?

Tags: support

Is it possible to cancel a close vote you have given or do I simply wait to reopen the question if it is closed?  After the OP reworded the question I feel it should stay open.

Comment: No. this is one of my least favorite features of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't rescind a close vote. However:

- Close votes expire if the question doesn't get closed (once it has been viewed enough times, and at a set rate as long as no new close votes are cast).
- Closing is not a permanent end state. If the question does get closed, it can be reopened. You are able to cast a reopen vote even if you cast a close vote (max of 1 each per question).

If the question has been edited to a point where you feel your close vote is no longer appropriate, then it's likely that either the question will not actually get closed, or it will be reopened rather easily.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Jim said about close votes not being reversible, I also want to add that the best thing you can do in this situation is to become an advocate for getting such posts reopened by drawing attention to those posts.

For instance, in cases where I've mistakenly voted to close, these are steps I've completed, with some success:

- Most likely, others may vote to close for the same or similar reasons as you did. Therefore, start by editing the post to eliminate the things that made you vote to close in the first place.  Editing will also bump the post to the top of the active page so others see it in its improved state.
- Ask follow up questions to the asker that may help him/her edit the post in a manner that helps convince others to vote to reopen or that prevents more close votes from accumulating. Make it clear you plan to vote to reopen the post -- if it was closed.
- After editing, post a link in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) and explain what you did to help fix the post. See if you can recruit more reopen voters. If you encounter more close voters, try to understand their concerns. See if you can alleviate those concerns with more edits or clarifying comments to the op.

In the end, we achieve a much better result than reversing the vote would have. Instead, you'll help turn a somewhat borderline question into a solid Q&A piece while also educating the asker on how to better word his or her questions in the future.

Comment: maybe it's a better result, but it's a pain to have to deal with the "oops" situation which should be solvable simply by removing your close vote